# How to implement SQL join on multiple keys for two tables using where clause?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I am interested to find the student headcount of  1st week of fall 2018 for the Business faculty by sex using the following two tables. Here ID is the primary key or part of the primary key for each of the data tables. In plan table, the program is the student's college(for our case, "Business"), Sex has values M, and F, TERM has the values, "Fall", "Spring", and " Summer", Sessions has the values, " 1st week", and " 2nd week". I was wondering if you could check my code. I am kinda new in SQL! I sincerely appreciate your time.

[image]

My SQL code:

```
SELECT count(Student.ID) as COUNT, Student.Sex as Sex
FROM Student JOIN Plan
on Student.ID=Plan.ID
WHERE Student.Term="Fall"
AND Student.Sessions="1st Week"
AND Plan.Program="Business"
GROUP BY Student.Sex;
```

Comment: What's wrong with the query? Have you tried it?

Comment: @tcadidot0 My potential boss asked me to write the query for the above tables. He did not give me the data. I wrote this query based on my basic understanding. I am not confident about this query!

Comment: If so, my advise to you is you need to have the ability to test your own query. You've been given the table schema example so why don't you just create a fake data to test your query? If you don't have any DBMS (MySQL) to test, you can use one of the online fiddle available like https://www.db-fiddle.com/ . At least with your own testing you know that this query will work and you can give a definite answer to your potential boss. Imagine when you ask here and some people said your query is correct then when he asks you if its correct, would you answer "that's what they said in SO"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway, I've created the fiddle for you reference here :

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7G2DwLB6SNqbAtKeD96nWG/1

And I can conclude that based on you query condition given, it is correct. But like @Benny mention, the field `ID` is usually referring to the tables data `ID`. For example `ID` in `Student` is the student id while in `Plan` its highly possible that its `ID` for each plan. But you said it's identical AND there's no `student_id` column in the `Plan` table, so it should be ok.

Comment: Thank u so much! I appreciate!

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this depends on whether or not the ID column in the plan table is the student’s id number , which i believe it is not. The plan table should have an entry for each student session combination, in order to account for the same student having different sessions. See: one to many relationship. From there, you should be able to execute this query after you group by all of the fields mentioned in the select clause.

Comment: ID is the student id here.